# Cannot successfully merge devserver patches together for deployment to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, python-2.7, django-admin

I have tried to push my new code to Heroku but I experiencing an `ImportError` which says:

```
Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver --insecure 0.0.0.0:13192 --noreload`
Traceback (most recent call last):
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
    from django.core.servers.basehttp import AdminMediaHandler, WSGIServerException, \
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/devserver/management/commands/runserver.py", line 3, in <module>
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
  utility.execute()
ImportError: cannot import name AdminMediaHandler
```

I have found in the documentation that `django.core.servers.basehttp.AdminMediaHandler` from 1.4 would be replaced with `django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers.StaticFilesHandler`.  My question is where do I place the `StaticFilesHandler` in place of the `AdminMediaHandler`?

Update:
I have now tried to merge the two patches together by placing `git+git://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver#egg=django-devserver` in my requirements. But I am still receiving the same error when trying to deploy

Comment: Based on this https://github.com/dcramer/django-devserver/issues/59 you have to merge the patch in your project so that it will update and remove AdminMediaHandler

Comment: I'm just gonna be honest with you.  I know a little git and I can merge two branches, but I have no idea how to merge the two devserver packages.  I have cloned the one you provided in the link to my computer, how would I merge the two packages?

Comment: I don't know :) I never done it. You should ask directly in that link on how to apply the patch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to try and merge the patches of django-devserver together.  Django-devserver 0.5.0 is compatible with Django 1.5, once I placed 'django-deveserver 0.5.0' in my requirements.txt my app could deploy without crashing.